# Can a CNAME point to an NS record?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a subdomain NS record which looks like this:

```
NS home ns1.nameserver.com
NS home ns2.nameserver.com
```

I'd like another subdomain `super` to point to the result of this NS name, but when I do:

```
CNAME super home
```

The name doesn't resolve.

This is a machine configured with dynamic DNS, hence `home` points to a 3rd-party dynamic DNS provider. To save myself the trouble of updating multiple dynamic DNS names, I'd like to simply have `super` resolve to the same IP address as `home`.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to also configure a dynamic DNS NS name for `super` which is updated separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly: yes.

Longer: This is a common misconception. CNAME points not an "NS record", but it points to *all* record type with the given name in the actual domain.

So, if you have a CNAME super home, it will point to *all* record type, if it is NS, A, or any other.

Comment: FWIW: In order to get things working, I had to use the FQDN in the CNAME like so: `CNAME super home.mysite.com`.